# React routing on conditional divs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Consider following snippet:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            
            showThird: false
        }

        this.showDivThree = this.showDivThree.bind(this)
    }

    showDivThree() {

        this.setState(prevState => ({ showSecond: false, showThird: !prevState.showThird}))
        console.log(this.state)
    }
  
  render() {
    return (
       <div className={'wrapper' + ( this.state.showThird ? ' show' : '')}>

                <div className="one">one
                    

                    {/* Show third */}
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={this.showDivThree}>{this.state.showThird ? 'hideThird' : 'showThird'}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="three">three
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={this.showDivThree}>{this.state.showThird ? 'hideThird' : 'showThird'}</button>
                        
                        <AnotherComponent />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
    )
  }
}

class AnotherComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {   
            
        }
       
    }

  
  render() {
    return (
       <div>
        <h4>Another component</h4>
       </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.one, .two, .three {
  background: #333;
  border: 2px solid #787567;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: border 0.2s, padding 0.2s, width 0.2s;
  min-height: 50vh;

}

.one {
  width: 100%;
}
.two {
  border-width: 2px 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 0;
}

.three {
  border-width: 2px 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 0;
}

.show .one, .show .two, .show .three {
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I want to implement routing here. I am using react-router and consider the full screen div-one is at the index route '/'. When I click on showThird, it basically opens another div and loads AnotherComponent in it. I want my route to change to say '/another'.

My goal is that such url '/another' is sharable and when someone hits that url he already sees the exact both half page divs with AnotherComponent loaded in right half.

How can I achieve his?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think changing the route completely from `/` to `/another` is a good idea. Since you're not really changing the page but rather only opening a panel on your `App`, changing the route is not really semantically correct thing to do.

Rather, if you want to make the open panel behavior shareable, you only have to set a query parameter that will be appended to the url, and you only need to check for it's presence when you mount your component.

For all your route components, react-router provides an object `location` into the `props` that will contain such query parameter you can use in your constructor to set the initial value.

On lick to open the panel, you only need to call the `push` method of react router to add your query string, and recall it to remove it when the panel is closed.

```js
class Route extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showThird: props.location.query.open
    }

  }

  openPanel = () => {
    this.props.router.push('/?open')
  }

}
```

Comment: okay! Could you perhaps show me small snippet for such a query parameter?

Comment: For what? Grabbing its value in the constructor?

Comment: How to set a query parameter that will be appended to the url when panel opens

Comment: Something like that should do it, you will need react router 3 though

Comment: Okay let me try this!

Comment: I suppose this Route component you created is essentially App in my case right? The one in my snippet?

Comment: It's been a good idea to separate the root app component and the route ones with react-router. This would be called Home